# Cloudflare to only encrypt traffic between client and CDN but non-secure connection from CDN to server

Tags: ssl, cdn, cloudflare

My server has a main site which have SSL certificate installed. There is also a linux management panel which runs on port 8080 that does not support SSL. What I want is that the traffic from the client to CloudFlare is encrypted with CloudFlare's certificate, but leave the connection from CDN to my VPS server non-secure. Right now the SSL/TLS encryption mode is set to flexible, edge certificates shows active, and also I've turned off "always use https". When i tried to access the 8080 port with https prefix however I couldn't get through. Can someone offer me a way to acheive this: traffic from client to CDN encrypted, while CDN connects unsecured to my server. PS: I'm using the free plan of CloudFlare and since it's a personal site and I do not want to induce extra cost, hope I can solve this with in the free plan.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve your problem using Cloudflare without any additional cost.

First of all turn ON **always use HTTPS**

1. Changing **Flexible to Full** in SSL/TLS setting in Cloudflare **(Simple Way, No need any other setup in your server)**.

Which will encrypt the data transfer from Cloudflare to your server using a self-signed certificate.

2. Changing **Flexible to Full(Strict)** in SSL/TLS setting in Cloudflare (Need some work in your server).

For Full(Strict), Go to your **origin server** tab in SSL/TLS and press create a certificate to get your SSL Certificate. But this certificate is only valid between your server and cloudflare.
[image: Cloudflare Origin server]

Then you need to install those certificates on your server.

**Additional Steps(As you don't have an HTTPS setup in your VPS):**

As you are using the port in your Webserver. So reverse proxy your application running on port 8080 using Apache, Nginx on the port 443. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68366971/10293794) for some idea.

Comment: Hi Aghilan, many thanks for your reply! I tried the first way which I suppose is eaiser, but nothing happened. I tried to dial in 8080 port with https but still get the prompt: "This site can’t provide a secure connection". I managed to get your point in way 2, which is to use the main site server (I have Nginx as my main site server) to forward the 8080 port to 443 so I can access it. However since I consider the linux management panel which runs on 8080 to be a more "primitive" service, I do not want it to rely on any other services on this server

Comment: ( so that I have access to it regardless of other services are down or not)

Comment: I think point 1 is not correct. In both cases we need to have a certificate on our server. With Flexible to Full, we can either use certificate generated by cloudflare or self-signed certificate. With Flexible to Full(strict) we need to have a verified/trusted certificate by CA for example let's encrypt certificates. Hope this helps.